# How to print a large image in C#?

Tags: c#, image, printing

Currently I am using the following code to print an image:

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    printpath = "C:\\temp.bmp";
    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(Print_Page);

    PrintPreviewDialog dlg = new PrintPreviewDialog();
    dlg.Document = pd;
    dlg.ShowDialog();
    pd.Print();
}

private void Print_Page(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
   Image i = Image.FromFile(printpath);
   Point p = new Point(0, 0);
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(i, p);
}
```

But if the image has a too large height, it doesn't fit the page. I want to split the image into pieces with height of 1125px and then show them on multiple pages in Print Preview. How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Use the DrawImage(Image, Rectangle) overload to size the image.